# What is the starting side of the "SYNC: Everything, Everywhere"?

Tags: android-netrunner

What side of card should I use when starting the game with the "[SYNC: Everything, Everywhere](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09001)" Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one with deckbuilding info (minimum deck size and influence limit), of course. That is, the one that reads "The Runner pays 1 credit more when spending a click to remove a tag (not through a card ability)."